# A fluid div is pushing a fixed div next to it down. It also isn't filling the expected height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have two divs next to each other - one fixed, and one fluid. However, whenever I apply a margin-top to a paragraph within the fluid div, it doesn't fill the whole height of the div and also pushes the fixed div next to it down with it. Unfortunately, I cannot use overflow:auto to fix this because I require the fluid div to have **overflow: visible** for a very specific need. Weird, I know, but I'm sure there must be a solution to this. However I've been trying for hours with no luck.

Here's a demo of the problem I'm having. I've included an explanation within the divs also: http://jsfiddle.net/LejbU/

```
<div class="left">
    <p>This div has a fixed width of 300px.<p>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <p class="withMargin">Test</p>     
</div>
```

-

```
.left {
background-color: yellow;
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
float: left;
}

.right {
background-color: pink;
height: 100%;
margin-left: 320px;
overflow: visible;

}

p {
margin: 0;
padding: 10px;
color: black;
}

p.withMargin {
margin-top: 100px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution I found. Create a new div WITHIN the right div and apply the following css to the new div:

```
.correctblock {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
zoom: 1;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/62ueY/

Answer (score 2):

That's because of the **collapsing margins** of CSS Box model definition:

[CSS 2.1 8.3.1 Collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or
>   might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins
>   that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined
>   margin is called a collapsed margin.

From the definition:

> Margins of inline-block boxes do not collapse (not even with their
>   in-flow children).

So change the display of `p.withMargin` to `inline-block` to avoid this behavior.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/LejbU/2/

Answer (score 1):

You've fallen victim to [collapsing margins (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

> Top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined into it, a behavior known as margin collapsing.

In your case:

> **Parent and first/last child**
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

There are a couple ways to get around this, I just use padding instead to change the layout as I require without changing other properties I consider more dangerous. In this scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/LejbU/1/

```
p.withMargin {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this also worked along with the display: inline-block solution.

Comment: @AndSmith Sure, though make note that a `display:inline-block` solution may have other consequences as you are actually changing the display type and, thus, changing the way the browser renders that element (say, if you had a few next to each other, etc). My solution not only keeps the element as a block type, but also work in (very) old browsers that do not support inline-block. old, tried and true solution.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I can see display:inline-block causing problems. The padding solution seems ideal.

For anyone else with this problem but with a div, wrap the div within another div and set the padding to the parent div.

Comment: @AndSmith and rgthree Margins and Padding are fundamentally different. If you were to add background image, background color... or borders, shadows... then you can't replace margin for padding. A `display:inline-block;` is *guaranteed* by the definition to behave as you wish and perfectly suits your situation.

Comment: @Arbel Right you are also Arbel. They both have their uses depending on the situation I guess.

Comment: @Arbel You've just proved yourself wrong! If you add a background to the `<p>` and give it an `inline-block` it _fundamentally changes_: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/s9Nvq/1/ `inline-block` comes with its own set of issues, such as this width issue as well as how it handles adjacent elements. You're not wrong about padding and margin being different, however, it's simply swapping two different yet related layout properties instead of _fundamentally changing the display_ of an element. As I said, there's tons of ways to fix the issue and for the asked scenario I've found this to be the cleanest.

Comment: @rgthree Read carefully: A display:inline-block; is **guaranteed** by the definition to behave as you wish and **perfectly suits your situation**.

Comment: @Arbel Sure, good job. The same exact statement for switching to padding since, by definition of collapsing margins, padding will never collapse with a margin. As I already said, your solution is not wrong but there are many more scenarios where `inline-block` could cause layout issues whereas padding is, again, in my opinion, optimal in this situation since _all it is doing is changing the rendered box to be inclusive of it's taken area_.

Answer (score 1):

add this `display:inline-block;` to `p.withMargin`